# Power series $ \sum_{r=1}^{n}x^{r}=\:?$

Tags: power-series

I want to know a formula for

$$\displaystyle \sum_{r=1}^{n}x^{r}=\:?$$

I can't say i can see where to derive it from at all.
Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: *Hint:* Geometric progression.

Comment: Almost surely this has been answered here before

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Write

$$S = \sum_{i=1}^{n} x^{i} = 1 + x + x^{2} + \cdots x^{n}$$

$$Sx = x + x^{2} + \cdots + x^{n+1}$$

So 
$$S - Sx= 1 - x^{n+1}$$

Can you try and solve for $S$ from here?

Comment: Oh, very nice! That's just what i wanted to see. Man i feel stupid. It's been a long day.
Thanks for making it so clear and simple.

Answer (score 1):

here is a way to do this we have

$$ (1-x)(x + x^2 + x^3 + \cdots + x^n) = x + x^2 + x^3 + \cdots + x^n - x(x + x^2 + x^3 + \cdots + x^n) $$

$$  = x + x^2 + x^3 + \cdots + x^n - (x^2 + x^3 + \cdots x^{n+1})   = x -x^{n+1}$$

$$ \Rightarrow x + x^2 + x^3 + \cdots + x^n = \frac{x^{n+1} - x}{x-1} $$

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$
S=\sum_{r=1}^{n}x^r.
$$
Note that
$$
xS=\sum_{r=1}^{n}x^{r+1}=\sum_{r=2}^{n+1}x^r,
$$
so that
$$
(1-x)S=\sum_{r=1}^{n}x^r-\sum_{r=2}^{n+1}x^r=1-x^{n+1}.
$$
So,
$$
S=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}.
$$